# Google maps add infowindow to marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

Hi i building a store locator and i found this code online its workind fine

```
function generateMarkers(points) {
  //var iconBase = "https://media.nisbets.com/static/content/banners/";
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var place = points[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[0], place[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      name: place[2],
      clickable: true,
      map: map,
      icon: /*iconBase + */"nisbets_storelocator_marker.png",
      url: place[3]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.location.href = this.url;
    });
    setMapBounds(marker.getPosition());
    markers.push(marker);
  }
}
```

But instead of a link who redirect to a page i want a popup window with the place info inside the popup.
Please i need your help how to add the infoWindow to my code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define a new InfoWindow

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: contentString
});
```

Add an event listener to each marker to open the InfoWindow.

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: Thanks how do i input inside contentString the value of position: myLatLng
      name: place[2]

Comment: var ContentString = myLatLng; @HappiOlivier